# Rewrite pages using Htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have htaccess enabled, and below is what I have written so far in.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

I would like to apply clean url to my pages
for instance, I would like

```
terms.php to be rewritten as /terms-and-conditions
privacy.php /privacy
thanks.php / thank-you
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probbly what you are looking for, though you may have to tweak it for your usage:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

That second rule can be used without change in the real http servers host configuration or in dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess` style files).

Obviously the rewriting module has to be enabled.

---

The last example you give, `thanks.php / thank-you` can *not* be implemented this way, since "thank-you" does not equal "thanks", but I assume that is a typo. If you really need that mapping, then you have to implement a special rule just for that single URI placed *before* that last rule above:

```
RewriteRule ^/?thank-you$ thanks.php [L]
```

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Answer (score 2):

You can try with following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^terms-and-conditions terms.php
RewriteRule ^privacy privacy.php
RewriteRule ^thank-you thanks.php
```

Comment: Thank you. How could I also do this in reverse such as typing /privacy.php is rewritten as /privacy.